# Create a foreign key from elements of a composite primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have two tables, translations and products. I do not have control over their layout, they just need to be imported into postgres from csv files.

```
┌─────────────┬─────────┐
│ language_id │ term_id │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           1 │       1 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           2 │       1 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           3 │       1 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           4 │       1 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           1 │       2 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           2 │       2 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           3 │       2 │
├─────────────┼─────────┤
│           4 │       2 │
└─────────────┴─────────┘


┌───────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ table_id references term_id   │ chair_id references term_id │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│                            1  │                          2  │
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

The table translations' primary key is a composite of `language_id` and `term_id` (can they both be integers with no problem ?)

And now the table products is referencing the table translations, but I am not sure how to create that relationship. `foreign key (table_id) references translations (term_id)` fails, due to `term_id` not being unique. Should I even be trying to create a relationship here ?

Comment: You need a composite FK to reference composite PK.

Comment: @Serg If I understood correctly I would need to know the `language_id` (runtime defined) while importing the table?

Comment: Alternatively you may wish to have 3 tables (+ Terms table) and  FKs Product-> Terms and FK Translations-> Terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two integers are fine for a composite primary key.  The syntax looks like:

```
 foreign key (table_id, chair_id) references translations (term_id, language_id)
```

Note that the columns need to be in the same order for the two column lists.

And yes, if this is a foreign key relationship, then I would suggest that you declare it to maintain data integrity.

Comment: I only get access to `language_id` during a query (since its runtime dependent) - so I don't think that this could work ... (column `language_id` referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist)

Comment: Also thanks for clarifying the two ints as composite keys thing

Comment: @Twiggeh . . . Based on the comments, you cannot define a foreign key.  A foreign key should refer to a *single* row.